# Partition a set into n subsets with elements with sum equal to m

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, matlab, mathematica

For example, given the set $a_n = \frac{n}{20}$ for $\,n \in \{1,\,2,\,\dots,\,19\}$, I would like to get **all** possible partitions of this set in 4 subsets such that the sum of their elements is always equal to 1.

Would you be so kind to write an algorithm in Mathematica, Matlab, or even in Excel?

Thank you very much!

Manuela

Comment: Good luck: the series sums to 9 1/2,  and the partitions of a set by definition include all elements of the set. Do you just mean 4 subsets, not necessarily a partition ?

Comment: I apologize: I've probably used bad language. I try to explain better. I have that set I "summary" with writing above (but in reality I have all the numbers written in a row). I have to divide them into 4 groups (let's call them A, B, C, D) such that the sum of the elements of A (and thus for B, C, D) is equal to 1. Then, behold, if we can write a more general algorithm, the better! Thank you!

Comment: Manuela: I think @Tom Collinge's point is that you will be left with a fifth group adding up to $5.5$.  Is that OK?

Comment: I can not figure out what you want to tell me. Sorry, it's just my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible. If such a partitioning were indeed possible, then, by adding all $4$ subsets together, we would get that $\underbrace{1+1+1+1}_4=\sum_{n=1}^{19}\dfrac n{20}=\dfrac1{20}\sum_{n=1}^{19}n=\dfrac1{20}\cdot\dfrac{20\cdot19}2=\dfrac{19}2\neq4$. See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. One last question: if the set of departure had: $\left\{0.5,\,0.1,\,0.15,\,\dots,\,0.95\right\}$ it would be equally impossible? Thank you for the patience that you have!!

Comment: @Manuela: I assume the first term was meant to be $0.05$ as oppsed to $0.5$. In which case $0.05+0.10+$ $+0.15+\ldots+0.95=0.5(1+2+3+\ldots+19)=0.5\cdot\dfrac{19\cdot20}2=19\cdot5= 95\neq4$.